# Error connecting to Mongo Atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, shared-hosting, mongodb-atlas

I am working on a nodejs project and using mongoose module I want to connect to Mongo Atlas,

I used

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://<USER>:<PASSWORD>@varcv-okhmh.mongodb.net/<DATABAS_NAME>?retryWrites=true');
```

but I got an error:

> failed to connect to server [varcv-shard-00-00-okhmh.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 35.158.192.211:27017]

I also try to connect via old connection string

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://peter:<PASSWORD>@varcv-shard-00-00-okhmh.mongodb.net:27017,varcv-shard-00-01-okhmh.mongodb.net:27017,varcv-shard-00-02-okhmh.mongodb.net:27017/<DATABAS_NAME>?ssl=true&replicaSet=varcv-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true');
```

But I got the same error.

**Notes:**

1. everything is working perfectly on my local machine the error is happens when I upload my code to Godaddy Linux Shared hosting.
2. I am using PM2 to run my server.
3. I am using Mongo 3.6.5
4. I am using mongoose 5.1.5

Comment: If it works locally and fails on the server, the problem is likely there. Your best bet is to contact hosting support.

Comment: Sounds like a whitelisting issue.  Is your GoDaddy IP allowed to connect in Mongo Atlas?

Comment: I allowed connecting from anywhere on mongo atlas